# Office 365 Sharepoint Rest calls

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, office365

Hi I'm trying to access some lists in Office 365 Sharepoint. I have managed to call the MyFiles list via the newer apis but I believe to call other lists you need to use the rest API. I am using the same access token I use to access the Files but the code below throws an unauthorised error. Does anyone have a any suggestions where I am going wrong?

```
string requestUrl = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml"));
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
      string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return responseString;
}
return "Problem";
```

Answer (score 1):

When authentication error occurs, Office 365 returns HTTP response that contains [`X-Ms-diagnostics` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595671%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

The header has the following format:

```
X-Ms-diagnostics = errorId ";" source ";" reason ";" fault
```

The `source` and `reason` properties contains the details about the error, for example:

```
Reason: Token contains invalid signature.

Source: invalid_client
```

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve the response error details:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, endpointUrl);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml"));
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
       var diagnosticsValue = response.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-diagnostics").FirstOrDefault(); 

    }
}
```